# How can I programmatically scroll an NSScrollView?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I want to slowly scroll down an `NSScrollView`, how can I do this?

I've tried setting the `.visibleRect` variable, only to find out that it's a get-only. I've also tried to `.scrollLineDown()`, which I assumed would scroll down one line, but apparently not. Besides, I want to be able to scroll smoothly, i.e. 1 pixel per frame. But, it's fine if I end up using a `Timer` and scroll a certain amount every, say, tenth of a second.

Comment: @the4kman might be, I'll see if that helps. Thanks

Comment: Yep, it worked. Sorry, not sure how I didn't find that one already